# How can I show timezone in TileMill?

Tags: tilemill, mapnik, natural-earth

I downloaded data from Natural Earth Data and added it to TileMill (git revision 8044976 on Mac)

I downloaded raster data, borders, cities, airports and timezones. However, the timezones show only a few odd ones. What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug in the data, TileMill or Mapnik?

[image]

[edit] I realised it may have something to do with the polygons. Those odd timezones are "closed" while most other timezones are more ore less straight lines from top to bottom. Maybe mapnik gets confused about what is the inside and outside of the polygon?

Comment: I have mentioned in IRC/#mapnik, but will also comment here. 1) Can you try loading the data in another program, such as QGIS, and see what happens there? 2) Perhaps the polygons are too large for the used projection, being larger (top and bottom), and mapnik (incorrectly) culls the polygons.

Comment: Re-saving in QGIS did the trick.

Comment: Great! Good to hear that it is solved.